# Can you go back to a specific line in your code?

Tags: java, return

I'm trying to make an index basically and if someone messes up I want them to be able to return to the last menu or the last selection screen, or just restart. Is this possible?

I'm using JCreator. It's my first program so I've kept it very simple; it's just a bunch of if-else statements. Looks a little something like this.

edit: Would it be easier if I made a restart button in the program interface or whatever you would call it?

```
public class Index
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What kind of sandwich are you looking for?");
        System.out.println("1. Ham   2. Turkey   3. etc.");
        int meat = key.nextInt();

        if (meat == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("What type of cheese would you like"?);
            System.out.println("1. Swiss    2. Cheddar   3. etc.");
            int cheese = key.nextInt();
            if (cheese == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Would you like lettuce and/or tomatoes?");
                System.out.println("1. Just lettuce   2. Just tomatoes   3. Both   4. Neither");
                int lOrT = key.nextInt();
            }
        }

        if (meat == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("What type of cheese would you like"?);
            System.out.println("1. Swiss    2. Cheddar   3. etc.");
            int cheese = key.nextInt();
            if (cheese == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Would you like lettuce and/or tomatoes?");
                System.out.println("1. Just lettuce   2. Just tomatoes   3. Both   4. Neither");
                int lOrT = key.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is a lot better now that you've posted your code so far. Thank you for that. I've tagged the question as [tag:java] as well. That'll help it land in front of Java programmers' eyeballs. In the future, I encourage you to flag offensive comments rather than respond with equal offensiveness.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as you describe it, but this is where **methods** come in.

A method (function in some other languages) is something which exposes repeatable behavior in a particular class, based on the object's state, which belongs exclusively to that instance of the object.

There are also `static` methods, or more formally, class methods, which are similar to normal methods with the exception that they generally don't depend on the state of the object to function appropriately.

In your case, what that means is a bit of a clean-up in your code.  Move everything that's common into one method.

---

Let's start with the lettuce and tomatoes bit.  Those two blocks are exactly the same.  Move them into one thing so that they can be referenced as such.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What kind of sandwich are you looking for?");
    System.out.println("1. Ham   2. Turkey   3. etc.");
    int meat = key.nextInt();

    if (meat == 1) {
        System.out.println("What type of cheese would you like?");
        System.out.println("1. Swiss    2. Cheddar   3. etc.");
        int cheese = key.nextInt();
        int lOrT = extractToppings(key, cheese);
    }

    if (meat == 2) {
        System.out.println("What type of cheese would you like?");
        System.out.println("1. Swiss    2. Cheddar   3. etc.");
        int cheese = key.nextInt();
        int lOrT = extractToppings(key, cheese);
    }
}

private static int extractToppings(Scanner key, int cheese) {
    if (cheese == 1) {
        System.out.println("Would you like lettuce and/or tomatoes?");
        System.out.println("1. Just lettuce   2. Just tomatoes   3. Both   4. Neither");
        return key.nextInt();
    }
    return -1; // sentinel return value - what to return when the if fails
}
```

Straightforward, no?  Let's take it up a notch - let's do some more work to refactor your code a bit.

The next thing is your `if` statements - they do the same thing regardless if `meat == 1` or `meat == 2`.  No sense in having them separate.  I'll collapse the `if` statements here and we arrive at...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What kind of sandwich are you looking for?");
    System.out.println("1. Ham   2. Turkey   3. etc.");
    int meat = key.nextInt();

    if (meat == 1 || meat == 2) {
        System.out.println("What type of cheese would you like?");
        System.out.println("1. Swiss    2. Cheddar   3. etc.");
        int cheese = key.nextInt();
        int lOrT = extractToppings(key, cheese);
    }
}

private static int extractToppings(Scanner key, int cheese) {
    if (cheese == 1) {
        System.out.println("Would you like lettuce and/or tomatoes?");
        System.out.println("1. Just lettuce   2. Just tomatoes   3. Both   4. Neither");
        return key.nextInt();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now we can comfortably move that into its own method as well - something like `extractCheese`. I'll also do a bit of general clean-up here to get it to feel more intuitive to you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What kind of sandwich are you looking for?");
    System.out.println("1. Ham   2. Turkey   3. etc.");
    int meat = key.nextInt();
    int cheese = extractCheese(key, meat);
    int toppings = extractToppings(key, cheese);
}

private static int extractCheese(Scanner key, int meat) {
    if (meat == 1 || meat == 2) {
        System.out.println("What type of cheese would you like?");
        System.out.println("1. Swiss    2. Cheddar   3. etc.");
        return key.nextInt();
    }
    return -1;
}

private static int extractToppings(Scanner key, int cheese) {
    if (cheese == 1) {
        System.out.println("Would you like lettuce and/or tomatoes?");
        System.out.println("1. Just lettuce   2. Just tomatoes   3. Both   4. Neither");
        return key.nextInt();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You could legitimately move the questions about meat into their own method as well...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    int meat = extractMeat(key);
    int cheese = extractCheese(key, meat);
    int toppings = extractToppings(key, cheese);
}

private static int extractMeat(Scanner key) {
    System.out.println("What kind of sandwich are you looking for?");
    System.out.println("1. Ham   2. Turkey   3. etc.");
    return key.nextInt();
}

private static int extractCheese(Scanner key, int meat) {
    if (meat == 1 || meat == 2) {
        System.out.println("What type of cheese would you like?");
        System.out.println("1. Swiss    2. Cheddar   3. etc.");
        return key.nextInt();
    }
    return -1;
}

private static int extractToppings(Scanner key, int cheese) {
    if (cheese == 1) {
        System.out.println("Would you like lettuce and/or tomatoes?");
        System.out.println("1. Just lettuce   2. Just tomatoes   3. Both   4. Neither");
        return key.nextInt();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

### Believe it or not, that's the easy part.

It's straightforward to write something that has the ability to return repeatable results.

Now comes the trickier part - using a `while` loop to retrieve valid information.  I'll leave the others to your implementation, but this is the general gist

- Get the input from the user
- Check its bounds
- Tell them it's invalid
- Loop and continue program execution.

Here's a snippet.

```
int meat ;
do{
    meat = extractMeat(key);
    if(meat < 1 || meat > 3) {
        System.out.println("Please enter valid meat.");
    }
} while (meat < 1 || meat > 3);
```

Once `meat` is within its bounds, your program will continue  executing.  I leave the rest of the implementation as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Whoa that's a handful lol. It'll take me a while to actually understand it, but thanks in advance. Could I still do the same thing if each option branched off into it's own thing? I just used sandwiches as an example because I was hungry heh. The real index I'm making has 1 main choice which branches off into 4 choices which branches off into 30 choices each and each of those 3 could have up to 3 more.

Comment: Also for the while loop do I put it after I ask all the questions about meat or right after I get the integer from the user?

Comment: You'd want a validation check for each input you receive.  Consider making that a method as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would change to a loop I changed your logic to methods for the Sudo Code this works at one tier do you need n tiers? If so you could extend this logic with nested loops allowing them to break back only to the last selection the same way you see here just with another loop for lettuce. Sudo Code Below:

```
int meatType = -1;
int cheeseType = -1;
bool canLeave = false;

do{
      meatType = MeatMethod();
      if(meatType == 1 || meatType ||2)
      {
           cheeseType = CheeseMethod();
           if(cheeseType == 1 || cheeseType== 2)
           {
               canLeave = true;
            }
      }
}while(canLeave);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a goto statement, but Java has no such thing--although it is a reserved word.

But, if I understand you correctly, what you want to do can be accomplished by using a loop and a break. For example:

```
while (true) {
    //ask the menu questions
    System.out.println("Did you mess up? Y/N");
    // get input
    if (answer=='Y')//they did mess up, so run loop again
    {
        continue; //goes back to loop's header
    }
    else //they didn't mess up
    {
       //break out of the loop 
       break;
    }
}
```